# Can marmite be made from brew yeast leftovers?

Tags: recipe, reusing-yeast, trub

If you don't know what marmite is you can stop reading now.

A friend of a friend reckons you can make marmite from the yeast leftovers of your brew. Does anyone know how to do this? Any one have a recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, apparently you can. There's a recipe for it here:

http://marmitelover.blogspot.no/2011/04/how-to-make-your-own-marmite.html

The author says she uses 'top fermentation from a brewery' - which I imagine is the krausen, although on a homebrew scale I wonder if that gives enough yeast.

She also mentions that it doesn't taste like the original - lacking the equipment to debitter the yeast, it's more bitter and beery. But sounded like a fun project to try.

PS: love/hate? Me, I hate Marmite! :-)

Comment: Great, thanks that's interesting. Was quite surprised to read that you use the krausen - I'd have thought the trub would be used ..

Comment: I've heard anecdotally that one of the major breweries in my city sell off their excess "post fermentation" yeast (presumably washed trub) to manufacturers of (the superior) Vegemite.

Comment: The update to the blog post mentioned that she ended up washing the yeast in a similar fashion to those who re-use the yeast in batches. This ended up removing a lot of the bitter flavors and off notes.